# DetailView Item Updating function in Edit Mode

Tags: asp.net

I have a drop down in a DetailsView in an Edit Mode.  I have about 10 fields in backend database but only using 4 fields in my DetailView.  The problem I am having is that I am only able to make updates the first time and it saves in my table but if I go back and try to make changes again then it won't let me do that.  What am I doing wrong here?  I have searched everywhere but couldn't find a solution.  Please help me or show me some examples as I am new to coding.  Thanks

Here is my code:

```
protected void DV_Mgr_Appr_ItemUpdating(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList DDList = (DropDownList)((DetailsView)sender).FindControl("DDList");
    //SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters["Sex"].DefaultValue = rblGender.SelectedValue; 
    DV_ManagerApp_DS.UpdateParameters["Approved1"].DefaultValue = DDList.SelectedValue;
}
```

Comment: can someone help or my question does not make sense ple help thanks